# error when creating "deployment.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes

I am new to DevOps. I wrote a deployment.yaml file for a Kubernetes cluster I just created on Digital Oceans. Creating the deployment keeps bringing up errors that I can't decode for now. This is just a test deployment in preparation for the migration of my company's web apps to kubernetes.

I tried editing the content of the deployment to look like conventional examples I've found. I can't even get this simple example to work. You may find the deployment.yaml content below.

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: testit-01-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 4
  #number of replicas generated
  selector:
    #assigns labels to the pods for future selection
    matchLabels:
      app: testit
      version: v01
  template:
    metadata:
      Labels:
        app: testit
        version: v01
    spec:
      containers:
        -name: testit-container
        image: teejayfamo/testit
        ports:
          -containerPort: 80
```

I ran this line on cmd in the folder container:

`kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml --validate=false`

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "deployment.yaml":
>   Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment:
>   v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Template:
>   v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: decode
>   slice: expect [ or n, but found {, error found in #10 byte of
>   ...|tainers":{"-name":"t|..., bigger context
>   ...|:"testit","version":"v01"}},"spec":{"containers":{"-name":"testit-container","image":"teejayfamo/tes|...

I couldn't even get any information on this from my search. I can't just get the deployment created. Pls, who understands and can put me through?

Comment: Please paste entire error message you got.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your yaml file.

This should work.

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: testit-01-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 4
  #number of replicas generated
  selector:
    #assigns labels to the pods for future selection
    matchLabels:
      app: testit
      version: v01
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testit
        version: v01
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: testit-container
        image: teejayfamo/testit
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

The problem was:

- `Labels` should be `labels`
- The syntax of `- name:` and `- containerPort` were not formatted properly in `spec.containers` section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. did rewrite the whole code putting in all the suggestions and locking out for more. It did run eventually and the deployment went live. Thanks. I think more needs to be done on error messages from kubectl though. That would greatly help with debugging. Thanks @mchawre. Your response helped.

Comment: In my case, one environment variable was not wrapped around double quotes!

Comment: DITTO to @Klaus, needed double quotes for env variables in **Helm** values.yaml when referencing yaml tree: `{{- toYaml .Values.app.env | nindent 8 }}`

Answer (score 45):

Since this is the top result of the search, I thought I should add another case when this can occur. In my case, it was coming because there was no double quote on numeric env. var. Log did provide a subtle hint, but it was not very helpful.

**Log**

```
..., bigger context ...|c-server-service"},{"name":"SERVER_PORT","value":80}]
```

**Env variable** - the value of `SERVER_PORT` needs to be in double quote.

```
env:
  - name: SERVER_HOST
    value: grpc-server-service
  - name: SERVER_PORT
    value: "80"
```

[Kubernetes issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/82296) for reference.

Comment: Great point! This is valid for any numeric value in the Env section.

Comment: wow this was exactly my issue..

Comment: My issue as well... +1

Comment: Thanks, I got this issue trying to launch Zookeeper. Error "Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field EnvVar.spec.template.spec.containers.env.value of type string"

Comment: Gor searchers I'll add booleans -- same issue "true" fixed it.

Comment: The mentioned Kubernetes issue got closed as "Works as intended".

Answer (score 0):

In short -> Syntax Error

The mistake I was doing:

```
ports:
  -containerPort: 8081
```

the above snippet causing the following error:

`Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating ".\\deployment.yml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Container.spec.template.spec.containers.ports of type []v1.ContainerPort`

And this is how I corrected:

```
ports:
  - containerPort: 8081
```

so the difference was
`-containerPort` (wrong one) and `- containerPort` (correct one).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, in my case, I turned up this result, but ultimately, the problem I had was that I had defined the same environment variable twice

Example:

```
...
env:
 - name: FOO
   value: "bar"
 - name: FOO
   value: "bar"
```